# Export HTML to PDF

Tags: export-to-pdf

I need to generate a PDF file from an existing pure HTML files when clicking 'Export' button. As I am working on the php project, a solution that can easily be used in a java-project is preferable.

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: you can either use a save as PDF link or use the HTML to PDF API at http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how well it would integrate into PHP, but I use pandoc for all sorts of document conversion. It can handle HTML to PDF.

http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library : [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/) or this one [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution , http://wkhtmltopdf.org/
This works really well for other html docs I have used